# Разбить текст на слова, избавившись от всех символов пунктуации и символов перевода строк

Tags: python, python-3.x, строки, split

**текстовый файл:**

```
Tratata - blabla, tutu
Tratata - blabla, tutu
```

разделить слова, убрать от них запятые, пробелы и \n разделение новой строки

```
for line in file:
            str = line.split(' ')
            #str = line.split('/n')
            #str = line.split(',') <-- как мне еще раз разделить текст? он выбирает последнее что записано
            print(str)
```

Comment: приведите в вопросе пример текста и того, что вы хотите получить на выходе

Answer (score 6):

Задаем в регулярке шаблон поиска и ищем через [findall](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.findall):

```
import re

text = """Tratata - blabla, tutu
Tratata - blabla, tutu"""

# Или короче: text = re.findall('[a-zа-яё]+', text, re.I)
text = re.findall('[a-zа-яё]+', text, flags=re.IGNORECASE)
print(text)  # ['Tratata', 'blabla', 'tutu', 'Tratata', 'blabla', 'tutu']
```

---

Как подсказал **Eugene Dennis**, можно сделать обратное поиску - разделение по символам через [split](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.split):

```
text = re.split('[^a-zа-яё]+', text, flags=re.IGNORECASE)
print(text)  # ['Tratata', 'blabla', 'tutu', 'Tratata', 'blabla', 'tutu']
```

При желании, можно указать параметр `maxsplit`, чтобы контролировать количества частей, по умолчанию он равен `0` - не имеет ограничений.

---

Можно сократить шаблон `a-zа-яё` и флаг `re.IGNORECASE`, используя шаблон `\w`, но это еще зацепит символы `_` (нижнее подчеркивание) и `0-9`:

```
text = re.findall('\w+', text)
print(text)  # ['Tratata', 'blabla', 'tutu', 'Tratata', 'blabla', 'tutu']
```

И, соответственно, для `split` (`\W` - это конструкция обратная `\w`):

```
text = re.split('\W+', text)
print(text)  # ['Tratata', 'blabla', 'tutu', 'Tratata', 'blabla', 'tutu']
```

Comment: c `re.split('[^a-zа-яё]+', text, 0, re.IGNORECASE)` немного короче и параметр `maxsplit` добавляется как опция

Comment: @EugeneDennis, если убрать `flags=`, а вместо `re.IGNORECASE` использовать альтернативное название, то станет короче `re.findall('[a-zа-яё]+', text, re.I)`. Но мне нравится писать полнее из-за наглядности -- думаю, в ответах так будет понятнее :) Спасибо за пример, добавлю

Comment: лучше заменить `'[a-zа-яё]+'` на `'\w+'` - выглядит лаконичнее и поддерживает символы из других языков (умляуты, иероглифы и т.д.)

Comment: @MaxU, ну, изначально так и хотел, но `\w` цепляет еще и `0-9` и `_`, а о них не говорилось :) В принципе, можно добавить с упоминанием

Comment: @gil9red, точно, совсем забыл об этой особенности...

Comment: @MaxU, все-равно спасибо за замечание, в любом случае, это полезно :)

Answer (score 3):

Сначала избавьтесь от всех символов пунктуации (можно воспользоваться [str.maketrans()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.maketrans)), после этого разбейте полученный результат на список слов, воспользовавшись [str.split()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) (`str.split()` без параметра разобъёт строку на слова по пробелам, табуляциям и символам перевода строки):

```
import string

tab = str.maketrans(string.punctuation, ' ' * len(string.punctuation))

text="""Tratata - blabla, tutu
Tratata - blabla, tutu"""

res = text.translate(tab).split()

print(res)
#['Tratata', 'blabla', 'tutu', 'Tratata', 'blabla', 'tutu']
```